# Removing data from 1 table using an entry list from 2 other tables

Tags: sql

Right at this moment do I have in one table orders on which I need to delete data from. In the table from where I need to remove rows from are there 2 connections. One of the connections refers to a table with the name/sub name of the customer.
I need to delete from these customers with a specific sub name in the orders table a certain number of product. To get the list of products I need to remove do I need to check into the third table at the price of it.

Below is the following query I have created but returned me an error on which I'm not really surprised.

```
    DELETE FROM `table1`
WHERE `entry` = (SELECT `entry` FROM `table2` WHERE `subname` = 'Buyer')
    AND `item` = (SELECT `entry` FROM `table3` WHERE `Price` != '226' OR '232');
```

Running this query got me to the following error..

> Error Code: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row
>
> Execution Time : 0 sec Transfer Time  : 0 sec Total Time     : 0.044
>   sec

Can anybody help me with the proper query setup?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subquery returns more than 1 row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357765/subquery-returns-more-than-1-row)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use IN clause instead of equality

If you were to remove customer records from table based just on customer name, your query would be like

```
DELETE FROM `table1` 
WHERE `entry` IN (SELECT `entry` FROM `table2` WHERE `subname` = 'Buyer')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be

```
DELETE FROM `table1`
WHERE `entry` IN (SELECT `entry` FROM `table2` WHERE `subname` = 'Buyer')
    AND `item` IN (SELECT `entry` FROM `table3` WHERE `Price` != '226' OR '232');
```